# C, post-decrement in operation

Tags: c, decrement

I've got a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a=3,b=8;
    b=(b--)*a;
    printf("%i", b);
    getch();
}
```

A compiler return 24 for b, and another one 23 (dev c++, first version 4.9.9.2 and the other with dev c++ version 5.x).

What's the right? And why?

Thanks.

Comment: Both are right (or wrong, howsoever you want to put it).  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Undefined Behaviour. You should avoid doing so.

Comment: (b--)*a should return 24, it becomes an undefined behaviour if you assign it to b.